# Access - query returns no result

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have tried to run the following query in Access 2013 but it gives no result.

```
SELECT PlayerID, RoundID, Rank
FROM P_7to8Ranking AS s
WHERE Rank IN
(
 SELECT  Rank 
 FROM P_7to8Ranking
 WHERE PlayerID = s.PlayerID and (s.Rank=1 or s.Rank=2)
)
ORDER BY PlayerID, Rank , RoundID DESC;
```

But when it is run in SQL Fiddle it works fine. Here is the Link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5260e/3.

It is driving me up the wall. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks odd... maybe I'm missing something but, doesn't this have the same effect and is easier and with better performance?

```
SELECT PlayerID, RoundID, Rank
FROM P_7to8Ranking AS
WHERE Rank IN (1,2)
ORDER BY PlayerID, Rank , RoundID DESC;
```

Did you try putting the table alias in the column selection?

Comment: The reason the code is like it is is because I was trying to re use some similar code. Although the code you have suggested works in SQL Fiddle it returns every entry from P_7to8Ranking when used in Access. Not sure if it makes a difference but P_7to8Ranking is the results of a query as well.

Comment: The query that I've posted, doesn't return any record in Access too?

Comment: the query you posted returns a result but it is every record that was in P_7to8Ranking.

Comment: Just to check, the table in the external select should be the same as the one in the inner select?

Comment: Try putting the condition "and (s.Rank=1 or s.Rank=2)" outside the inner query

Comment: If you mean after the bracket but before the ORDER BY i just tried that but it returns no results.

Comment: I really don't know how to help you further with the available data. The problem should be elsewhere and not in the query. I have created an Access database with the same data and all queries works fine, with same results, including yours.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it but the previous query  P_7to8Ranking was created using the code 'SELECT P_7to8Calcs.PlayerID, P_7to8Calcs.RoundID, P_7to8Calcs.PlayedTo, P_7to8Calcs.DatePlayed, RankMe([PlayerID]) AS Rank
FROM P_7to8Calcs
ORDER BY P_7to8Calcs.PlayerID, P_7to8Calcs.PlayedTo, P_7to8Calcs.DatePlayed DESC;' and a module function 'Function RankMe(PlayerID As Long) As Long
   Static LastID As Long
   Static RankNum As Long
   If PlayerID <> LastID Then
      RankNum = 1
      LastID = PlayerID
   Else
      RankNum = RankNum + 1
   End If
   RankMe = RankNum
End .